# Jupyter notebook This site can’t be reached

Tags: ipython, jupyter

Every time I launch the Jupyter notebook using

```
jupyter notebook
```

I get a

```
Connection refused: localhost:8888
```

I have to replace localhost with 127.0.0.1 for it to work.
While 127.0.0.1 notebook is messed up

This occurs with all browsers I use:

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Your antivirus/firewall is acting up, or your network config is messed up. Localhost should resolve to 127.0.0.1. Something is interfering with this normal process for some reasons.

Comment: I already tried to turn off antivirus to see if it is the reason for this and tried to unset the proxy from chrome settings still same result